# Pseudorandom Algorithm for VERY Large (10^1.2mil) Numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I'm looking for a pseudo-random number generator (an algorithm where you input a seed number and it outputs a different 'random-looking' number, and the same seed will always generate the same output) for numbers between 1 and 95<sup>1,312,000</sup>.

I would use the [Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) PRNG, but if I did, I would have to convert the seed number (which could be up to 1.2 million digits long in base-10) into a binary number, which would be so massive that I think it would take too long to compute.

In response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413686/numeric-reversible-pseudorandom-number-generator-for-very-large-numbers), the Feistel cipher was recommended, but I didn't understand the vocabulary of the wiki page for that method (I'm going into 10th grade so I don't have a degree in encryption), so if you could use layman's terms, I would strongly appreciate it.

Is there an efficient way of doing this which won't take until the end of time, or is this problem impossible?

Edit: I forgot to mention that the prng sequence needs to have a full period. My mistake.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) I didn't down-vote but I imagine you did for one of these reasons: (1) way too much extraneous information in this question, even if you have "hidden" it, (2) it's like you're asking a bunch of questions so it's unclear what you really want, which makes me think (3) you're suffering from asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try editing your question to fit the community standards for a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and it will be easier to get help.

Comment: To clarify - I'm not convinced you need a random number generator and your explanation of what you're actually trying to do is very confusing

Comment: Yes, please condense this to the problem you need to solve.  Try to write a concise description of the library problem, and then a concise description of your current research and implementation problem.  In short *why*, followed by *how*.

Comment: You do have a problem in that your PRNG appears to require a period of at least the range of numbers it can produce ... and likely much more than *that*.  You have a problem that is *intrinsically* long to compute, even with the reduction to LFSR.  If you want the RNG to cycle with any sort of pseudo-randomness (e.g. any one choice is equally likely to follow any other), you need a period that is at least the *square* of your range.  One way or another, that's going to take a ship-load of bit-banging.

Comment: If you're at a point of needing to generate a 2.6 million **digit** random number, that's probably a good time to turn right around and figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: @HFBrowning Thank you for the advice. I think I made the question unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Yeah; you just want a very (very) long number. A very long number is just data. You can create any length number you want by using any random number generator for long enough. A 2-hour long MPEG movie is just "a number" that happens to be a very large number. So there's nothing complicated here. You don't need specialized systems. Just seed a random number generator and run it until you have the size "number" you want.

Comment: Note that they only claim to have 10^4677 books (29^3200), not 95^1,312,000 (or 26^1,312,000), so you're trying to solve a **significantly** more difficult problem (to say the least). Not sure how they got that number though, maybe each book only (necessarily) has a different first page and the rest are arbitrary. There's a reason it's not more. We're not magicians.

Comment: should be 10^2.4mln, isn't it?

Comment: Why is it important that it is full-period? Even using a supercomputer, it isn't feasible to iterate through anything more than a vanishingly small percentage of the positive integers <= 95^1312000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with modulus `m = 95^1312000`.

The formula for the generator is `x_(n+1) = a*x_n + c (mod m)`. By the Hull-Dobell Theorem, it will have full period if and only if `gcd(m,c) = 1` and `95` divides `a-1`. Furthermore, if you want good second values (right after the seed) even for very small seeds, `a` and `c` should be fairly large. Also, your code can't *store* these values as literals (they would be much too big). Instead, you need to be able to reliably produce them on the fly. After a bit of trial and error to make sure `gcd(m,c) = 1`, I hit upon:

```
import random

def get_book(n):
    random.seed(1941) #Borges' Library of Babel was published in 1941
    m = 95**1312000
    a = 1 + 95 * random.randint(1, m//100)
    c = random.randint(1, m - 1) #math.gcd(c,m) = 1
    return (a*n + c) % m
```

For example:

```
>>> book = get_book(42)
>>> book % 10**100
4779746919502753142323572698478137996323206967194197332998517828771427155582287891935067701239737874
```

shows the last 100 digits of "book" number 42. Given Python's built-in support for large integers, the code runs surprisingly fast (it takes less than 1 second to grab a book on my machine)

Comment: How do we guarantee that `c` and `m` will share no common factors other than 1? It seems like if `c` could be any number between `1` and `m - 1`, `c` is likely to share at least one common factor with `m`. Also, thank you very much for the reponse

Comment: @IkeBishop `c` is a specific number, determined by the seed (1941, chosen on a lark). I tested that it was relatively prime with `m`, initially by using `math.gcd()`, though it suffices to check that neither `c%5` nor `c%19` are zero.

Comment: Right, I mistakenly thought that `c` and `a` would be different every time you ran the code, but you are correct. I think it's nice that the year the story was published happens to be a seed that produces a full period for LCG. Very clever, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method that can produce a pseudo-random digit, then you can concatenate as many together as you want.  It will be just as repeatable as the underlying prng.

However, you'll probably run out of memory scaling that up to millions of digits and attempting to do arithmetic.  Normally stuff on that scale isn't done on "numbers".  It's done on byte vectors, or something similar.

Comment: A generically-chosen RNG won't be sufficiently random when concatenated into a number that large.  The first **M** digits will uniquely indicate the remaining **M-N**, with N >> M.

Comment: I assumed that would be ok, since the question indicates that a LFSR would be suitable, which would have the same property.

Comment: This is a very good point. However, in the question I forgot to mention that the prng sequence needs to have a full period (my bad). Would a concatenate method work and still produce a full period?

Comment: It depends what algorithm you use.  General purpose prngs are usually not that robust.